# WriteFileGather - What is the way to write huge files(bigger than 4 GB)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, io

I am using windwos xp and i want to append data (about 4 MB each time) to a file.
Using 'WriteFileGather', i increase the offset's value of the overlapped struct all the time.
Since the the system call is a 32 bit, the offset value(DWORD) can not exceed 4GB value.

Code sample:

```
LARGE_INTEGER size;
if (!GetFileSizeEx(_hFile, &size))
{
    return;
}
overlapped.Offset = size.QuadPart;
```

Using the ftell and fseek is not working for me. 
Apparently, 'WriteFileGather' requires the overlapped.offset value to be assigned.

What is the way to exceed the 4G limit?

Answer (score 4):

`WriteFileGather` takes an `OVERLAPPED` structure from which it gets the offset within the file at which writing starts. This offset is split into a high and a low doubleword (`Offset` and `OffsetHigh`), so it's really a 64-bit offset.

So, if you want to use `WriteFileGather` (personally, I wouldn't), this is no hindrance. You cannot write more than 4GB *in one go* (but you wouldn't want to do that anyway!), though the total file length or the offset into the file can be a lot larger than that.

Comment: In Windows, the recommended way to convert a 64-bit value into `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` is to use a `LARGE_INTEGER` union.  Write the 64-bit value to `QuadPart` then copy `LowPart` to `Offset` and `HighPart` to `OffsetHigh`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That's actually a terrible way, which exists only to accommodate languages which don't have 64-bit integer types.  When you do, simple bit-shift and bit-mask does the job, and doesn't break the language rules for unions use.

Comment: @Ben: that's not why the technique exists; after all, if you don't have a 64-bit integer type, you can't write to QuadPart in the first place.  However, I suppose it *is* preferable (as a matter of principle) to use the language-standard-supported approach, despite its disadvantages.  (But it should be noted that the Win32 API uses `LARGE_INTEGER` often enough that if the compiler can't handle it you're probably in trouble anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, but 64 bit versions of ftell and fseek exist for Windows and Linux. For Windows, it's [_ftelli64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx) and [_fseeki64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx). For Linux, it's [ftello64](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3s/ftello64) and [fseeko64](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3s/fseeko64).